# C: Compile optimization for picosat SAT solver

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-optimization

I am trying to optimize the C program picosat, which is a SAT solver. My last program ran 24 hours, so an optimization might safe me hours.

- [picosat](http://fmv.jku.at/picosat/)

NOTE: picosat is single threaded only! multithread SAT solving is an open problem.

My plan was to try to compile picosat with multiple C compilers, to look which compiler produces the fastest code.

However, I faild at compiling

Any tips how I can optimize for performance? I only applied `-O3` so far, and just for completness, `-O4` didn't improve the performance.

If it matters, this is my CPU:

```
processor       : 23
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 44
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5650  @ 2.67GHz
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 0x10
cpu MHz         : 1596.000
cache size      : 12288 KB
physical id     : 1
siblings        : 12
core id         : 10
cpu cores       : 6
apicid          : 53
initial apicid  : 53
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes lahf_lm arat epb dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 5333.19
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: -march=native -mtune=native and try -Os, it can be faster than -O2 and -O3 sometimes, and depending on the computation involved -ffast-math

Comment: Using a different compiler is just the first step, and will only work worth a damn if the code was written correctly.  Taking a look at the code...eh.  It's like 90% macros and gotos, and gives the compiler very little leeway to optimize.

Comment: Brute force optimization of picosat itself or applying the algorithm to a real-life problem? In any case, I would not start with the compiler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the comments are pointing out, that code is not particularly easy for the compile to optimize. If you're looking to make any significant improvements, you'll need to begin changing code. Strength reductions would be an easy place to start and would probably shave several hours off your computations.

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2012, I compiled `Picosat 936` under *Windows* using *Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express*.
It was not easy. Especially, if you want to compile for 64 bits address space, the memory alignment and address arithmetic were tricky. Compilation under *Linux* should be far easier.

You could have a look at [Plingeling](http://fmv.jku.at/lingeling/), a multi-threaded SAT solver developed at the same university.

*Plingeling* ist faster than (the elder) *Picosat* for many cases.

Other fast SAT solvers are [Riss3g](http://tools.computational-logic.org/content/riss3g.php),  [Cryptominisat](http://www.msoos.org/cryptominisat2/) or [Z3](http://z3.codeplex.com/).

[SAT Competition 2013](http://satcompetition.org/2013/) provides a good overview of the current state of the SAT solving art.

If your SAT solving runs take too long, it might be worthwhile to improve your problem encoding. Sucessful SAT encoding techniques are reviewed in [this paper](http://jsat.ewi.tudelft.nl/addendum/Bjork_encoding.pdf%E2%80%8E).

Comment: Do you have your binaries somewhere?

Comment: I am probably not entitled to spread Picosat binaries. Sorry! Windows binaries for SAT solvers Clasp and Z3 can be readily downloaded at the respective homepages.